# Display salary, Avg(salary), Name for those who earns more than company Avg(salary)

Tags: sql, oracle

how to display the name, salary and the avg(salary) for all the employees whose salary is greater than the company avg(salary).

I have tried the following query:

```
Select last_name, salary
From employees
Where salary >(select avg(salary) from employees);
```

This gives the names of those employees who are getting higher salary than the company avg(salary). But I want to display the avg(salary) in the select list aswell.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you use?

Comment: You already know how to get the average salary, so what is the question here?

Comment: I am using Oracle @Hamlet Hakobyan

Comment: @Burhan Khalid. Yes I know the avg(salary) amount. But I just want to display it in the result aswell.

I want it in the following format (for example):
Name Salary Avg(salary)
A    15000    12300  
B    17500    12300
D    12400    12300
M    21000    12300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the employee table to a query that produces the average:

```
select last_name, salary, avg_salary
from employees
join (select avg(salary) avg_salary from employees) x
  on salary > avg_salary
```

This query will work on all databases.

Comment: It really helps. But not sure why have you used the 'as' at the last ?

Comment: @user2788235 Oops! "as" was a stupid choice for a table alias. It was supposed to be the initials of Average Salary, but "as" is of course a reserved word. I've changed it to simply "x" in the query.

Comment: Actually I am a newbie in SQL and Pl/SQL. Learning is the only thing I can do now. It would be better if I can get your Email id for further help & suggestions. 

Thanks,
Kuntal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sql server, here is but one of many ways to accomplish this:

```
DECLARE @AverageSalary MONEY

SELECT @AverageSalary=AVG(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES

Select last_name, salary, @AverageSalary From employees Where salary > @AverageSalary
```